# How to organize dll files in project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, organization, external-dependencies

I would like to organize library files in my project. I currently have about 30 libraries (devExpress, system (winforms), system (others), project references) in a single project. Is it possible to organize such a view?

[image: libraries]

For example, is the way to create a directory structure in Visual Studio for that file types in the solution? Something like this:

- References/

  - devExpress (including DevExpress dlls)
  - system (all system dlls)
  - projectDependencies

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing so?

Comment: Better organization of files. Currently, there are too much and without tools like Resharper, NDepend hard for me to control it.

Comment: OK, so you need to get the list of 3rd party DLLs that are dependencies for your application? I do not see a reason to track standard .Net DLLs. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Mainly I'm interested in the separation of external libraries (devExpress, DI tools, our framework dlls). It is easier to manage such a structure (depending view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot alter the way that the References view looks in Visual Studio. However, you can add a folder to your project and put all 3rd-party DLLs in that folder for the sake of organisation.

[image]

You can then add those DLLs as references to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it is not possible to apply any kind of sorting or structuring onto the referenced assemblies.

Maybe you should think about restructure your code files by separate them into multiple projects and each then only needs a sub part of the long list of references.